# Linux diff get only line number in the output

Tags: linux, diff

I want to use linux `diff` command to get the following output:

```
2,4c2,4
```

I only want to know the line numbers where the files are different. I don't want the actual line on the console.

Eg:

If I will execute the following command:
`diff file1.txt file2.txt`

I would like the following output:

`2,4c2,4`

I don't want the output:

```
2,4c2,4
< I need to run the laundry.
< I need to wash the dog.
< I need to get the car detailed.
---
> I need to do the laundry.
> I need to wash the car.
> I need to get the dog detailed.
```

I went through the manual of `diff` command but I wasn't able to find any option that would allow me to achieve what I want.

Comment: A wealth of information can be found in info diff, check it out, I am sure you'll find something

Comment: hey John Rambo ! Does any of the below answer your question ?

Answer (score 5):

Pipe it to `grep` and only show lines beginning with numbers.

```
diff file1.txt file2.txt | grep '^[1-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

pass the flag -f .

```
-sh-4.1$ cat file1.txt 
 I need to run the laundry.
 I need to wash the dog.
 difdferen line 
 I need to get the car detailed.


-sh-4.1$ cat file2.txt 
 I need to run the laundry.
 I need to wash the dog.
 I need to get the car detailed.

-sh-4.1$ diff -f file1.txt file2.txt 
d3
```

Edited as per @Barmar comment: for it to work on changed lines .. you can just filter lines with `"<" or ">"`  by asking for the inverse of lines that start with `"<" or ">"`

First : plain diff :

```
-sh-4.1$ diff file*
3d2
<  difdferen line 
4a4
>  different line in file2
-sh-4.1$
```

with grep to filter lines that start with < or >

```
  -sh-4.1$ diff   file* | egrep -v "^<|^> |^-"
```

3,4d2
5a4

```
3d2
4a4
```

simplified version suggested by @Barmar

```
-sh-4.1$ diff file1.txt file2.txt  | egrep -v  "^[-<>]"
3,4d2
5a4
```

Comment: That works for deleted lines, not for changed lines.

Comment: and also not for added lines

Comment: Thanks @Barmar  for the feedback . updated the answer .

Comment: is --- a line or just something that separates  the diff of the two files ? not sure

Comment: No, it separates the two versions when it's a change, not an addition or deletion. Look at the output in the question.

Comment: added one more filter to account for dashes.

Comment: You can simplify it to `^[-<>]`